# RaycastHit2D doesn't detect touch on gameobject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm trying to detect touch on selected gameobject using RaycastHit2D. The game is 2D. Below is my code :

```
 void Update()
{
    if (Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        Debug.Log("touch");
        Vector3 touchPosWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
        Vector2 touchPosWorld2D = new Vector2(touchPosWorld.x, touchPosWorld.y);
        RaycastHit2D hitInformation = Physics2D.Raycast(touchPosWorld2D, Camera.main.transform.forward);
        Debug.Log(hitInformation.collider);
    }
}
```

I have attached that script to empty gameobject. Then create a prefab with a box collider in it. But when I touch the prefab with boxcollider2d on it still says Null. What's wrong with my code

Answer (score 0):

I've found the problem now change this

```
Vector3 touchPosWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
```

to this

```
Vector3 touchPosWorld = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.GetTouch(0).position);
```